# Where can I find the implementation of "class DispatchQueue : DispatchObject"?

Tags: swift, multithreading, dispatch-queue

I am interested to learn more about the implementation details of `class DispatchQueue : DispatchObject`.
I have looked [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/search?q=DispatchQueue), and [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/search?q=Dispatchqueue) but I can't find the matching implementation.

Comment: Is on the Apple doc only the declaration?

Comment: Yea, thats all I see and it specifies that it is in the Dispatch Framework.

Comment: `DispatchQueue` is the imported name for `OS_dispatch_queue` (see  https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/34f383d34450d47dd5bdfdf675fcdaa0d0ec8031/src/swift/Dispatch.apinotes#L59-L60), which appears to be... a protocol? https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/34f383d34450d47dd5bdfdf675fcdaa0d0ec8031/src/internal.h#L131

Comment: Good find! Thats so weird, I wonder why the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue) says that it is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't find this in the Swift code because it isn't Swift. This is just a front end for Cocoa's `OS_dispatch_queue` etc., which are not open source. It's not part of the Swift library; it's an iOS thing, not a language thing.